# What does "if in location" context mean in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration

In the Nginx documentation, context for some directives ([error_page](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive for example) is given as follows:

> Context:  http, server, location, if in location

My question is, what does **"if in location"** context mean? I've been googling but couldn't find a proper explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two distinct contexts for an [`if` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if), **server** and **location**.

The behaviour in these two contexts are [quite different](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Example:

```
server {
    if (...) { ... }

    location ... {
        if (...) { ### }
    }
}
```

The first `if` block is in `server` context. The second `if` block is in `location` context.

The context **if in location** specifies directives that may appear within the ### section in the above example.